# sublimeRepl will not take input with enter key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

Whenever I enter input into the REPL window and hit enter, the system continues to make new lines instead of submitting the input. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Found the solution, in the key bindings file you have to decide with key combination with enter will make a newline, and which will actually submit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experience the same, it happens when you copy all default keymap setting to user setting file, I guess this is keymap conflict.

The solution is quite simple, just keep the part you change in user file.

Answer (score 0):

In the keybindings section make sure to check which key combination will insert a newline and which will actually submit the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are running python 2.x instead of python3. In Python 3, the input function works as you are expecting, but in 2.7 it tries to interpret it as python code.

You need to edit the Main.sublime-menu file, it's located:

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python
```

Here you just need to put the number of the version 3 in some order, as in the configuration file posted on this gist: 
https://gist.github.com/Hckmar9/e1cb87b67a9836db4d26#file-main-sublime-menu